# How to Extract a Specific XML Node using SED

Tags: xml, unix, sed

First time posting here but not the first time using Stack Overflow as a resource. Must say this site has been integral to my work in general.

I have used `sed` in so many ways before but can't seem to figure out how I can return the full XML node, if and only if, one of its child nodes meets certain criteria. I know how to use the 2 addresses convention (`/START/END/command`) but need to restrict the result only to specific matching child nodes.

Example:

```
<entity id="001">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <country>US</country>
</entity>
<entity id="002">
    <name>Jose Reyes</name>
    <country>Mexico</country>
</entity>
<entity id="003">
    <name>Juan Dela Cruz</name>
    <country>Philippines</country>
</entity>
<entity id="004">
    <name>William Shatner</name>
    <country>US</country>
</entity>
```

If I want to return the full entity node with id `003`, I can use the following command:

```
sed -n '/entity id="003"/,/<\/entity>/p'
```

However, if I want to return the full entity nodes that match the country `US`, how should I go about that one?

I don't mind doing the work myself if you can point me to a general direction. In fact, I do prefer that one over spoon feeding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have seen in comments on similar questions, the best thing for processing XML is a tool made for processing XML, and not a general text processing tool like sed or awk.

For example if you have access to `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//entity[country = 'US']" file.xml
<entity id="001">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <country>US</country>
</entity><entity id="004">
    <name>William Shatner</name>
    <country>US</country>
</entity>
```

Especially if you're going to be working with XML more than a little bit, I would put the effort into researching the available command line tools more suited for parsing XML.

If you're really stuck then `awk` would be a better option than `sed`, and `awk` should be available anywhere sed is:

```
$ cat a.awk

/<entity id/ { f = 1; s = "" }

f { s = s ? (s ORS $0) : $0 }

/<country>US</ { f = 2 }

/<\/entity>/ {
    if (f == 2) print s
    f = 0
}

$ awk -f a.awk file.xml
  <entity id="001">
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <country>US</country>
  </entity>
  <entity id="004">
    <name>William Shatner</name>
    <country>US</country>
  </entity>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely look into the `xmlstarlet` tool. Was just wondering if it's possible with `sed` if that's the only tool available given that I may not have the ability to install additional tools on a customer's server.

Comment: I definitely understand about not necessarily having control over the target environment, been there! I added an awk solution (if you have sed you would surely have awk as well). Just be aware that it's a more brittle situation that depends on the XML being formatted in a certain way whereas an xpath based solution only depends on the XML being valid.

Comment: Thank you! I do like the `xmlstarlet` solution better. Combined with `xpath` expressions, this is certainly a better tool for command line XML parsing (or the like). Should be able to figure out a way to get that introduced to the customer's environment if the need arises. I could certainly run it in my local cygwin installation regardless. I completely agree that the `awk` script would be dependent on how the XML was formatted.